# C# WinForm RemoteApps

Tags: winforms, remote-desktop, remoteapp

I wrote a WinForm application that will be remotely accessed via RDP. I am having issues with the sound being transmitted to the client.

I am using the following to trigger a Beep. It is working as expected when I launch the app from my development box. However, when I access it via RDP, It is not beeping.

```
 Console.Beep();
```

I am wondering if there is a better alternative or anybody aware of a workaround.

Comment: Did you enable "Play at my machine" in the RDP client?

Comment: Also, see here: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2495012?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: thanks for your link I"ll forward it to the Sys Admin.

Comment: It looks like it was enabled. I came up with a solution. I'll update the thread shortly.

Comment: `Console.Beep` runs at a different level than `RDP`. It uses the old Bios Speaker instead. So in all likelyhood the remote box was beeping away happily. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to directly play an audio file. I tried `Console.Beep`and `System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play` with no luck!

```
 Console.Beep(); // It didn't work. 


 System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play(); // IT didn't work either 


  // Playing directly a wave file produced audio. 
  using (var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\ding.wav"))
  {
    soundPlayer.Play(); // can also use soundPlayer.PlaySync()
  }
```